# What are AssemblyKeys used for, and how to import them?

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark

In a recent popular sbt app https://github.com/databricks/reference-apps, I found a line that required me to

```
import AssemblyKeys._
```

This line doesn't compile in SBT or in my IntelliJ IDEA.

What is the import used for and why is it necessary?

Comment: The acute issue is quite simple to solve - you just have to get the project directory structure right.  but i think a good explanation of AssemblyKeys and the idiomatic usage of them would still be quite useful as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The other answer by @mfirry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26194741/1305344) pretty much answers what part of the build (definition) brings `import AssemblyKeys._`. It's the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin that (quoting [the docs of the plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#sbt-assembly)):

> Create a fat JAR of your project with all of its dependencies.

It's needed by the plugin to do its job.

You may ask yourself why I would need the plugin at all.

Since you didn't reference the application that requires the import and hence the plugin, and I didn't review the examples, either, I can only guess by the company Databricks that's the commercial entity behind [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) the examples use.

In order to deploy an application onto a cluster of Apache Spark you need to *assemble* the entire application and configure the workers so they can access the binaries (with the necessary dependencies, namely jars). That's the aim of the `sbt-assembly` plugin to pack all up and offer a single application jar so Spark can use. See [Standalone Applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#standalone-applications) in the documentation of Apache Spark to read about the standalone case (no cluster environment):

> For sbt to work correctly, we’ll need to layout SimpleApp.scala and
>   simple.sbt according to the typical directory structure. Once that is
>   in place, we can create a JAR package containing the application’s
>   code, then use the spark-submit script to run our program.

You may want to read [Cluster Mode Overview](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html) to have an overview of how to deploy a Spark application onto a Spark cluster.

Answer (score 5):

With the latest version, we no longer need to import the `AssemblyKeys._`

Check upgrade guide [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/master/Migration.md#upgrading-with-bare-buildsbt)

Comment: This is important. Answers above is outdated.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#sbt-assembly) plugin.

You basically need to

- add the following line to a file, say `assembly.sbt` (or really any `*.sbt` file), under `project` folder in your sbt project:

  ```
  addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
  ```
- put the import line at the top of your `build.sbt` (in the directory that the `project` subdirectory is under).

  ```
  import AssemblyKeys._
  ```

With the above files, the very basic project structure should look as follows:

```
➜  myProjectName  tree
.
|-- build.sbt
`-- project
    `-- assembly.sbt

1 directory, 2 files
```

Comment: Yup. The key is the nested project directory